# Java lightweight library for QBE (non-JPA) open source / free?

Tags: gratis, open-source, java

I am looking for a freeware or open source java library that, given a JDBC connection, it can assemble/execute a QBE query, hopefully, using a POJO or HashMap as example.

It does not have to deal with multiple tables.

Unfortunately, I can't just add JPA solutions such as OpenJPA, Hibernate or iBatis in this project.